# Show hidden div on ng-click within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm working on an Angular.js app that filters through a json file of medical procedures. I'd like to show the details of each procedure when the name of the procedure is clicked (on the same page) using ng-click. This is what I have so far, with the .procedure-details div set to display:none:

```
<ul class="procedures">
    <li ng-repeat="procedure in procedures | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
        <h4><a href="#" ng-click="?">{{procedure.definition}}</a></h4>
         <div class="procedure-details">
            <p>Number of patient discharges: {{procedure.discharges}}</p>
            <p>Average amount covered by Medicare: {{procedure.covered}}</p>
            <p>Average total payments: {{procedure.payments}}</p>
         </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm pretty new at angular. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, you really don't need a href="#" in the a element.

Comment: You do if you want to pass an HTML validator.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Remove the `display:none`, and use `ng-show` instead:

```html
<ul class="procedures">
    <li ng-repeat="procedure in procedures | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
        <h4><a href="#" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">{{procedure.definition}}</a></h4>
         <div class="procedure-details" ng-show="showDetails">
            <p>Number of patient discharges: {{procedure.discharges}}</p>
            <p>Average amount covered by Medicare: {{procedure.covered}}</p>
            <p>Average total payments: {{procedure.payments}}</p>
         </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/asmKj/

---

You can also use `ng-class` to toggle a class:

```html
<div class="procedure-details" ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! showDetails }">
```

I like this more, since it allows you to do some nice transitions: http://jsfiddle.net/asmKj/1/

Comment: How to hide the first div when I click on second div.

Comment: To answer the Q above... Just change the ng-class to hidden on true....

ng-class="{ 'hidden':  showDetails }"

Answer (score 28):

Use `ng-show` and toggle the value of a `show` scope variable in the `ng-click` handler.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pvtpenguin/wD7gR/1/

```html
<ul class="procedures">
    <li ng-repeat="procedure in procedures">
        <h4><a href="#" ng-click="show = !show">{{procedure.definition}}</a></h4>
         <div class="procedure-details" ng-show="show">
            <p>Number of patient discharges: {{procedure.discharges}}</p>
            <p>Average amount covered by Medicare: {{procedure.covered}}</p>
            <p>Average total payments: {{procedure.payments}}</p>
         </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How to hide the first div when I click on second div.

Comment: This puzzles me... how does this "scope" variable work? When I try it, all are hidden!?