# css transition effect on ng-class

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to apply a transition duration when my trash-content shows up. I've been trying to use a solution seen on [Show hidden div on ng-click within ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660826/show-hidden-div-on-ng-click-within-ng-repeat#), precisely the variation suggested by Joseph Silber. I don't understand why it's working on his example but not on mine. I'd like the div to slowly resize.

**HTML part**

```
<div id="trash" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="test">
    <div class="trash-content" ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! showDetails }">
        <ul>
            <li class="trash-li" ng-repeat="e in elems"> <a>{{e.title}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button id="trash-btn" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails" ng-class="{ 'big': showDetails }">Trash</button>
</div>
```

**CSS part**

```
.trash-content {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 2px 0px;
    color: rgb(102, 103, 105);
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 2s;
    -moz-transition: 2s;
    -o-transition: 2s;
    transition: 2s;
}
.hidden {
    max-height: 0;
    max-width: 0;
}
```

*Full problem on Fiddle :* http://jsfiddle.net/63xoxx37/1/

Comment: what is the problem? its slowly opening and closing! what is it supposed to do?

Comment: It was the wrong URL, I've changed it. But the effect is supposed to be the same

Comment: your going to have to use width, in order for a css transition to fire it needs  a start value and an end value. It gives a strange animation when I use it in the fiddle, but I kinda like it

Comment: Ho okay, I get it ! Thanks a lot. Can you write a answer ? I'll tag it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (use `opacity:0;` instead of `display:none;`):

```
.trash-content {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 2px 0px;
    color: rgb(102, 103, 105);
    transition: 2s linear all;
    -webkit-transition: 2s linear all;
    opacity: 1;
}
.h {
    max-height: 0;
    max-width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
   }

    <div id="trash" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="test">
        <div class="trash-content" ng-class="{ 'h': ! showDetails }">
            <ul>
                <li class="trash-li" ng-repeat="e in elems"> <a>{{e.title}}</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button id="trash-btn" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails" ng-class="{ 'big': showDetails }">Trash</button>
    </div>
```